# Facebook problem

Tags: password, facebook

My iPad, which I've been using daily for the past 3 years, all of a sudden is asking for my Facebook password constantly.  I first noticed that one of my games would not connect to Facebook.  It connected fine the day before but now it won't.  When I went to the FB tab in settings it was blank.  I entered the password.  It verified it and it all looked good.  I exited out of settings and tried to enter my game and a box popped up asking for my password again.  It does that until I hit cancel.  I can still access FB thru the app and thru the browser.  Any ideas anybody????

Answer (score 3):

I remember dealing with something like this for a friend over a year ago. One of the things to try is to make sure you're logged out of FB at your computer and any other device you may log into FB on with.  Then, do a reset on your iPad (don't worry, this won't hurt any of your data): hold the Home and Power/Sleep buttons down at the same time for approximately 15-20 seconds/until you see the Apple logo.  Then release and give it time to fully restart. It'll take a few minutes, so be patient.  After it fully starts up, try opening up FB and entering in your login credentials and see what happens.

Comment: Something I remembered from this earlier problem I dealt with: It seems to me that I remember even after we'd logged out of FB at all of her devices (iPhone, iPad mini and iPad) the problem persisted.  Turned out she had another FB page associated with her primary FB page, though with a separate login. I can't remember how I sorted that out but suffice it to say int he beginning it was pretty frustrating, including the fact that FB support is so minimal. Hopefully this isn't your problem.  If so, let me know and I'll try to find some of my notes on this issue.